# Question regarding making an earthquake detector circuit

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am a beginner in the subject of electronics. I am planning to do an earthquake detector circuit (https://www.electroschematics.com/seismic-sensor/).  I need to know what to look for regarding the piezo element (lead zirconate crystal) used in the circuit.

First what is going with the piezo element? What is happening here actually?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Unfortunately the web page you linked to has little information about what kind of piezo pickup it is or what are important parameters for finding a compatible piezo. Basically, it's a random circuit with no details, a common feature of hobby electronics, so it is not a professional reliable earthquake detector. You can try any piezo you can find and see if it works even a bit. The piezo just senses mechanical vibrations and converts them to electrical signal that is amplified and large enough signal starts tone generation.

Comment: @Justme can you suggest  any professional websites that just doesn't just show random circuit with no details ,I am planning to do a simple project for my electronics paper any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: > it’s no more than the usual piezo buzzer disk with one end fixed and a weight attached to the other.

Comment: Just about everything about that circuit is wrong, from the use of VR, to a 741 at 9 V, the symbol for C2, to a 741 trying to drive an NPN like that, to using an inverting amplifier with a piezo, to giving no info at all about the piezo. Good luck!

Comment: @Neil_UK I guess I should use books then ,like Electronics for Dummies

Answer (score 0):

For your information, here is what happens in this circuit.
The generator used is triangular (should "mimic" "seismic wave").
Differentiator "behavior" for low frequencies.
Respond (Vce) only on the fast "positive" ramp part of the signal (shown as red) ...

[image]